Could someone explain why resolving the wall pursuit game dilemma is considered a significant breakthrough?
I recently read about a solution ('Rate of Loss Characterization That Resolves the Dilemma of the Wall Pursuit Game Solution' by D. Milutinović and others) to the long-standing dilemma in the wall pursuit game using advanced methods from differential games and optimal control theory. They used the viscosity solution of the Hamilton-Jacobi-Isaacs (HJI) equation, to analyze the game:
$$\min \left\{ \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + H(x, \nabla V), V - g(x) \right\} = 0$$
By applying a rate of loss analysis on the singular surface, they identified a saddle point that determines optimal strategies, even where classical analysis fails.
The saddle point in a game is a point $(x^*, y^*)$ such that:
$$\max_{y} \min_{x} L(x, y) = L(x^*, y^*) = \min_{x} \max_{y} L(x, y)$$
where $L(x,y)$ is the loss function (or payoff function) in the game. In this context:

$x$ represents the strategies of the pursuer.

$y$ represents the strategies of the evader.

$L(x,y)$ captures the rate of loss in the wall pursuit game.


This results in a complete game optimal solution for all game states.
- Q1: Could someone explain why resolving the wall pursuit game dilemma is considered a significant breakthrough?
- Q2: And what are the real-life potential benefits of this discovery?
